# Importing TimeStamp data from KML into GeoDataFrame using Python

Tags: python, geopandas, kml, geodataframe, timestamp

I have a KML file that I have converted from Garmin *.FIT* to KML via GPSBabel. The resulting KML file looks to be fine. Example (Note: I have changed coordinate values so they don't point anywhere specific)

```xml
<Placemark>
  <name>WPT019</name>
  <TimeStamp>
    <when>2020-07-29T11:18:10Z</when>
  </TimeStamp>
  <styleUrl>#waypoint</styleUrl>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>-9.518110,39.776503,522.20</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>
```

I am trying to create a GeoPandas (0.10.2) Dataframe using Python 3.7 with the co-ordinates as the Geometry Point Data and I have managed to do this as you would expect via Fiona/GeoPandas

```py
gpd.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'
df = gpd.read_file('testkml.kml', driver='KML')
```

Which yields:

```
    Name    Description geometry
20  WPT021      POINT Z (-9.29851 39.85655 522.60000)
21  WPT022      POINT Z (-9.22857 39.91654 522.60000)
22  WPT023      POINT Z (-9.25863 39.64651 522.80000)
23  WPT024      POINT Z (-9.25870 39.82643 523.20000)
24  WPT025      POINT Z (-9.26879 39.39621 524.40000)
```

How do I read other data into the DataFrame from the KML i.e. TimeStamp or Placemark Name?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a separate Python XML/KML parser rather than GeoPandas/Fiona

```py
import geopandas as gpd

gpd.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'
df = gpd.read_file('mytestplace.kml', driver='KML')
df.head()

 Name     Description                  geometry
0  Start1              POINT Z (-122.53623 37.86047 0.00000)
1  Start2              POINT Z (-122.53642 37.86030 0.00000)
2  Start3              POINT Z (-122.53669 37.86007 0.00000)
3  Start4              POINT Z (-122.53692 37.85986 0.00000)
4  Start5              POINT Z (-122.53712 37.85961 0.00000)
```

With [`fastkml`](https://github.com/cleder/fastkml) for example (use [`pygeoif`](https://github.com/cleder/pygeoif) or [`shapely`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) for geometry)

```py
from fastkml import kml

with open('mytestplace.kml', 'rb') as myfile:
    doc = myfile.read()
 k = kml.KML()
 k.from_string(doc)
 features = list(k.features())
 points = list(features[0].features())
 stations = [{'name': p.name,'time': str(p.timeStamp),'geometry': p.geometry} for p in points]
 # ESRI Shapefile does not support datetime fields therefore str(
 gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(stations)
 gdf.head()

 name                   time                          geometry
 0  Start1  2007-01-14 21:05:02+00:00  POINT Z (-122.53623 37.86047 0.00000)
 1  Start2  2007-01-14 21:05:20+00:00  POINT Z (-122.53642 37.86030 0.00000)
 2  Start3  2007-01-14 21:05:43+00:00  POINT Z (-122.53669 37.86007 0.00000)
 3  Start4  2007-01-14 21:06:04+00:00  POINT Z (-122.53692 37.85986 0.00000)
 4  Start5  2007-01-14 21:06:24+00:00  POINT Z (-122.53712 37.85961 0.00000)
```

Comment: This is excellent - thank you. My biggest issue currently is actually finding out what is available as there are loads of predefined tools/libraries which can get lost in the Google/DDG results.I was just about to post a workaround I cobbled together using xml Element Tree Library, putting the relevant nodes into a list then creating a GDF from three separate lists of a list  Time, CO-Ordinates, Names. This way is *much* cleaner.